# Drop values from pandas array, based on index

Tags: python, pandas

Probably been asked before, but can't find an answer that works for me.

I have a reasonably large array, made up of 3 unique class names. I'm trying to create 3 new arrays, based on index values. Using the Fisher's Iris data set (as it's smaller and useful to test on), I've tried using the following code:

```
iris_ds.set_index("Class")

iris_SA = iris_ds.drop("Iris-versicolor", axis=0)
iris_SA = iris_SA.drop("Iris-virginica", axis=0)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "AAA.py", line 18, in
>   
>       iris_SA = iris_ds.drop("Iris-versicolor", axis=0)
>
> File "C:.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line
>   3940, in drop
>       errors=errors)   File "C:.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line
>   3780, in drop
>       obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
>
> File "C:.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 3812, in _drop_axis
>       new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
>   File "C:.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 4965, in drop
>       '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask])) KeyError: "['Iris-versicolor'] not found in axis"

Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Are you reassigning `set_index`?  `iris_ds = iris_ds.set_index("Class")`  `set_index` is not an inplace operation.

Comment: Thanks. worked perfectly. Can you set as an answer and will mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure you are reassigning the `set_index` statement, `set_index` is not an inplace statement.

```
iris_ds = iris_ds.set_index("Class")
```

or

```
iris_ds.set_index("Class", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of answering the question, may I mention a wonderful tool named `df.groupby()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'class':['a']*2+['b']*3+['c']*3,
    'other': np.arange(11,99,11),
})

print(df, '\n\nafter groupby:\n\n')

for classname, classdf in df.groupby('class'):
    print('classname:\n', classname,  '\nclassdf:\n', classdf, sep='', end='\n=====\n')
```

output:

```
  class  other
0     a     11
1     a     22
2     b     33
3     b     44
4     b     55
5     c     66
6     c     77
7     c     88 

after groupby:


classname:
a
classdf:
  class  other
0     a     11
1     a     22
=====
classname:
b
classdf:
  class  other
2     b     33
3     b     44
4     b     55
=====
classname:
c
classdf:
  class  other
5     c     66
6     c     77
7     c     88
=====
```